# Sphinx Filters - Can I have an 'OR' between filters attributes?

Tags: database, search, sphinx

I'm using sphinx to list me some items from my database here.
It's almost 100%, I just haven't figured out yet how to create an `OR` between two different filters. For example:

My Object in the database has a starting and an ending date, I can `filter(starting_date, x, y)` and `filter(ending_date,x,y)`, but both filters will have to return true to bring me the object, how can I say to sphinx filter this attribute, or that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx uses | for or

as in "black" OR "white" would be "black" | "white"
http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#boolean-syntax

Comment: that works when filtering the attribute value, but i need to filter one attribute or another.

Answer (score 6):

Asked and answered on the Sphinx Forums.

Only possible in 0.9.9, using the SetSelect.

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3577

Comment: Thanks! Your answered saved me lot's of time! I've never thought that you can filter by setselect values

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of having `OR` logic across different attributes in Sphinx. Normally, there's two possible work-arounds:

1. Have one multi-value attribute with both sets of values you want to match against - and filter on arrays of values.
2. If it's the same OR logic every time, combine it into a single boolean attribute, having the SQL statement do the initial hard work.

Using timestamps makes things a bit more difficult though - MVAs are only for integers at this point... are you after all objects that are occuring at a specific time? Or something else?

Comment: Correction: as noted by Ben, this is possible in Sphinx, using the Select option.